# ASP.Net Connection to Access

Tags: asp.net, ms-access-2010

This is my code, but I can't insert data into the MS Access Database

```
protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" 
            + @"Data Source=E:\Parhai\Semester 06\Web\Assignments\i140097_Assignment_02\i140097_a02\i140097_a02\Database\Survey.mdb; Persist Security Info=False";
        con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        con.Open();
        using (con)
        {
            cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO [Person] (Gender, Age, Occupation, Income) VALUES (" + gender.Text + ",'" + age.Text + ",'" + occup.Text + ",'" + income.Text + ")");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", gender.Text.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", int.Parse(age.Text.ToString()));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Occupation", occup.Text.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Income", int.Parse(income.Text.ToString()));
            lbl_show.Text = "Added!!!";
        }            
    }
```

Comment: I think the error is due to ExecuteNonQuery...
Am I supposed to add it?

Comment: Adding ExecuteNonQuerry gives me an exception ... 
What to do????

Comment: Based on the code you posted, you never execute the SQL. Then your comment mentions an error...   you are missing the:   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: what does is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining parameters, but your command text has no parameters placeholders.
As usual, when concatenating strings, it is really easy to fall for some syntax errors. In you database *Gender* appears to be a string field, so you need quotes around the value. On the contrary, *Age* seems to be an Integer and you don't need quotes, and so on...

So the first step is to ditch the string concatenation and just use the parameters defined below.

```
cmd = new OleDbCommand(@"INSERT INTO [Person] 
       (Gender, Age, Occupation, Income) VALUES 
       (@Gender, @Age, @Occupation, @Income)", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", gender.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", int.Parse(age.Text));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Occupation", occup.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Income", int.Parse(income.Text));
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

And another problem is the missing connection when you build the command.
By itself the command is not able to know on which database it should execute. You need to pass the OleDbConnection as the second parameter to the OleDbCommand constructor or just set the Connection property before executing the command.

Of course, the command needs to be executed at the end of the day.....

NB. I have also removed the ToString() after the Text property of those TextBoxes. Text is already a string, no need to convert it to a string.